# Read excel file with pandas and store values into Python dict with the column names as keys

Tags: python, pandas

I have following excel:

```
type        name          latitude    longitude
--------------------------------------------
area        area1         50.33       4.23
building    building1     -           -
```

I'm using pandas to read in the excel file using following function:

```
def read_excel(self,sheet_name):
    df = pd.read_excel(io=self.excel_file, sheet_name=sheet_name)
    dict = df.to_dict()
```

I get following output:

```
{
  'type': { 0: 'area', 1: 'building' }, 
  'name': { 0: 'area1', 1: 'building1' }, 
  'latitude': { 0: 50.33, 1: nan }, 
  'longitude': { 0: 4.23, 1: nan }
}
```

I would like to have the following output:

```
[
    {
         'type': 'area', 
         'name': 'area1',
         'latitude': 50.33, 
         'longitude': 4.23
    }, 
    {
         'type': 'building', 
         'name': 'building1', 
         'latitude': nan, 
         'longitude': nan
    }
]
```

To achieve this, I have written the following function:

```
def read_excel(self,sheet_name):
        df = pd.read_excel(io=self.excel_file, sheet_name=sheet_name)
        dict = df.to_dict()

        objects = []

        for i in range(0,len(df.index)):
            temp = {}
            temp['type'] = dict['type'][i]
            temp['name'] = dict['name'][i]
            temp['latitude'] = dict['latitude'][i]
            temp['longitude'] = dict['longitude'][i]
            objects.append(temp)

        print(objects)
```

This produces the output I want. However, I would like to have a solution that is more dynamic, e.g. that I don't need create a temp dict with assigning statically column names.

Any suggestions to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try orienting it as `records`:

```
print(df.to_dict(orient='records'))
```

Answer (score 1):

pass `orient='records'` to `to_json` :)

always refer to the documentation as a debugging step!
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html